# Uploading a video to youtube from iOS app returns 400

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, swift3, multipart

I have an iOS(swift) app in which I can log in through my google account and get an access token.

After retrieving the access token I am making a post request to YouTube for uploading the video.

The error returned is as follows

```
{error =
{code = 400;
errors =({domain = global;
location = part;
locationType = parameter;
message = \"Required parameter: part\";
reason = required;});
message = \"Required parameter: part\";};}"
```

Following is the code that I am using to make a post request.

```
 func postVideoToYouTube(token: String, callback: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){
        if videoPath == nil {
            return
        }
        var movieData: NSData?
        do {
            movieData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: (videoPath?.relativePath)!, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.alwaysMapped)
        } catch _ {
            movieData = nil
            return
        }


        let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]
        let URL = try! URLRequest(url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos", method: .post, headers: headers)
        print("Video Data",movieData)
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(movieData as! Data, withName: "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")
        }, with: URL, encodingCompletion: {
            encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint("SUCCESS RESPONSE1: \(response)")
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):

                print("ERROR RESPONSE: \(encodingError)")
            }
        })
    }
```

Earlier the error was 403 forbidden , but I have added "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl" to scope and now I am getting a 400.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It says it requires a "part" parameter in the HTTP request, what does the Youtube API say it needs for that paramater and why isn't it in the request? (I'm pretty sure it's not the MultipartFormData but some other parameter that Youtube wants)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in the return data is interesting:

```
Required parameter: part
```

It tells you that a parameter named `part` is required, and you have not included that in your call so that is why you are getting an error.

If you look at the [Youtube API description](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) you can see a description of the `part` parameter.

For instance

> The part parameter serves two purposes in this operation. It identifies the properties that the write operation will set as well as the properties that the API response will include.

And

> The following list contains the part names that you can include in the parameter value and the quota cost for each part:
>
> - contentDetails: 2
> - fileDetails: 1
> - id: 0
> - liveStreamingDetails: 2
> - localizations: 2
> - player: 0
> - processingDetails: 1
> - recordingDetails: 2
> - snippet: 2
> - statistics: 2
> - status: 2
> - suggestions: 1
> - topicDetails: 2

OK..that may not make a lot of sense but fortunately there are some examples as well.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video) is a link to an example using python.

If you look at that example the interesting part (no pun intended) is here:

```
# Call the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
    part=",".join(body.keys()),
```

OK, so we join the keys of something called `body` and that ends out being the value of the `part` parameter.

Next question...how is `body` defined?

```
body=dict(
  snippet=dict(
    title=options.title,
    description=options.description,
    tags=tags,
    categoryId=options.category
  ),
  status=dict(
    privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus
  )
)
```

So...the keys of `body` must be `snippet` and `status`. If you look at the valid values mentioned in the list described by "The following list contains the part names that you can include in the parameter value" above in my answer,  you'll see both `snippet` and `status` there, so they seems valid.

So in short, you should add the `part` parameter when you do a POST request to the YouTube API. The value of that parameter could be `snippet, status` but you should probably read up on exactly what that means and whether you should use something else.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Great. I added a snippet and it work's like a charm. Thank you